# Problems programming LPC1343 microcontroller in Ubuntu

Tags: microcontroller, usb, linux, programmer, cortex-m3

When I copy a binary that works on a lpc1343 to the mounted usb-device representing the lpc1343 flash, the binary file is changed and does not work. Doing the same with the flash mounted via usb on Windows or Mac OS does not have the same problem. What could be the problem, and how can it be fixed?

Edit: The problem seems to be the vfat implementation in Linux which seems to prefix 0s before the file to be transferred.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's the same binary? How exactly do you copy the file under Ubuntu? Have you tried different ways of copying?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I found the problem. It seems to be the way linux deals with vfat. It seems to prefix 0s before sending the file which are ignored by a lot of usb devices, but still is incompatible to the standard.

Comment: When you say it prefixes 0s before sending the file what do you mean? How do you know? Are you copying a working binary (that you can get working on a windows/mac) or are you copying a binary created on your Ubuntu machine? What steps do you go through to copy the binary across? What settings do you have in fstab for the usb-device? Are you doing it as root, or as a non-privileged user? Do you click and drag, or are you copying at the command line? If there is a problem with Ubuntu, executables and vfat devices why is it not more commonly known? You think there's a published standard for vfat?

Comment: We have send the same binary from a windows, a mac os, and a several linux machines. We have copied from command line, copy and past in file browser as well as drag and drop. The reason why it is not more commonly known, is because most usb devices tolerate these 0s (I guess just drop them), however, the vfat implemented on the lpc1343 does not (which is according to standard). When using mcopy from mtools in unix on the block device, instead of mounting the vfat, the file is transferred correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that the binary is padded with an unspecified number of 0 s at the start? You appear to have a working solution to this problem, why not post a more detailed answer below to allow others to share this knowledge more easily. I see from following the link in your profile that you've got over 10k of rep points from various SE sites so you know the drill by now.

Comment: I believe it is padded with 1024 0s. At least I have been told so. I will write an answer here with the solution when I have time.

Comment: got time? :P I would be very interested in the solution. thanks.

Comment: I don't think Linux is doing anything that is outside the USB mass storage specification; it's really the fault of the chip's simplistic bootloader.  At least that was the conclusion I reached when looking into the same problem a year or two ago.

Answer (score 3):

you can solve this by using `mtools` (userspace fat utilities):

```
mdel -i /dev/sdf ::/firmware.bin
mcopy -i /dev/sdf new_firmware.bin ::/
```

Comment: This is how I've always done it.  It's a good solution to a poorly written bootloader.

Comment: what does the -i option and the :: do ?

Comment: "The drive letter : (colon) has a special meaning. It is used to access image files which are directly specified on the command line using the -i options". You can read about them in manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html#drive-letters).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the simpleflash python script from the r0ket[1] git repository. It writes directly to the device instead of using "cp". I had to modify the size at line 20 from 32 to 64 to work with a LPC1347 test board...

The script can be found [here](https://github.com/r0ket/r0ket/tree/master/tools/bootloader).

[1] [LPC1343 board](http://r0ket.badge.events.ccc.de/)